# Is a stand-alone wallet for an ERC20 compatible token a possibility?

Tags: wallets, erc-20

Assuming that there is an ERC20 compatible token deployed on the Ethereum blockchain, is it possible to:
1. Have a stand-alone wallet solely for this token (not an Ether wallet + watching a token, but a dedicated app). Maybe some existing open source solutions?
2. Is it required to download the full Ethereum blockchain in order to be able to send\receive those custom tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a standalone wallet solely for this token?

Yes.

> Is it required to download full Ethereum blockchain in order to be able to send\receive those custom tokens?

No. You can run a lightwallet.

> Maybe some existing open source solutions?

Iconomi released an ERC20 Token (ICN) and has an [ICN-only wallet available](https://ico.iconomi.net/login) via their ICO page. I do not believe it's open source, but they do have a [contact page](https://ico.iconomi.net/contact-us).

Alternatively, [ConsenSys has published an Ether Lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) (MIT License) - although, this would be an Ether wallet + watching a token.